# How to enumerate fake audio speaker output devices on Firefox Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am trying to automate webrtc audio/video web app on Firefox browser, using Selenium.
I use fake streams for that purpose by settings capabilities:

`"media.navigator.streams.fake": True`

Recently firefox made some changes with audio output device detection on browser. They set this by default.

`"media.setsinkid.enabled": True`

Problem is, after this, I can see a dropdown to select audio output device on my browser while running automation but there is no option in the dropdown. It works for camera/ microphone though.

Firefox version - 118

My capabilities:
`"permission.default.camera": 1, "permission.default.microphone": 1, "media.navigator.permission.disabled": True,`

I tried to set this for audio output but it didn't help:
`"permission.default.speaker-selection": 1,`

Wondering what capabilities I need to add?